# How to create previous-dart objects from dart2js output?

Tags: dart, dart2js

Assumed that I code some type of library and convert it to js (per dart2js). How can I access the prototypes to create objects? What is right way to resolve dart-namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose functions to JavaScript

- [Expose Dart functions to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669163/expose-dart-functions-to-javascript)
- [Dart SDK 0.8.10.3_r29803 dart:js callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800265/dart-sdk-0-8-10-3-r29803-dartjs-callbacks)
- [Using Dart with JSON Web Services](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/) (it's used for JSONP)

see also [js library](http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js.html)

I don't think there is a way to expose classes to JavaScript, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: thx for your answer, but I am rather looking for a way to use js (dart2js output) within js projects. And your links describe possibilities to use js within dart.

Comment: But each of the links contains an example how to expose a Dart function to JavaScript so that the Dart function can be called from JS. I haven't seen anything that goes more in the direction you want.